# How can I strip data from website table using ruby?

Tags: ruby, xpath, datatable, nokogiri

For example, I only want `"1:30pm"` from this data that I got using xpath:

```
"1:30pm Manila Bulletin"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish it is `"1:30pm Manila Bulletin".split(/\s/).first`.

Comment: Thank you! What if I want two words or more?

Comment: I have this code:

[:time_of_race, 'tr[1]/th/a/text()'.split(/\s/).first],

and all it did is erase the entire :time of race when I puts it.

Comment: The resulting object is an array, so you can access it using indices.
e.g. `arr = "1:30pm Manila Bulletin".split(/\s/)` then `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` where you get `"1:30pm"` and `"Manila"` respectively.

Comment: I'll search for indices. Thank you! I just learned about ruby last week, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: If you want the first two words, you can do something like this `arr[0..1].join(" ")`

Comment: Hi, I can't still get what I want :( this is my full code, maybe you could help? Sorry:

Comment: table = doc.xpath('//table')
details = table.collect do |table|
 detail = {}
 [
# time of race, convert time to Manila
 [:time_of_race, 'tr[1]/th/a/text()'.split(/\s/)],
# race number
  [:race_number, 'tr[1]/th/a/span[1]/text()'],
    
# name of race
  [:name_of_race, 'tr[1]/th/a/text()'],
    
# purse
  [:purse, 'tr[2]/td/b/text()']

].each do |name, xpath|
    puts table.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end
  detail
 time = details[0..1].join(" ")
 puts time
end